# What is the equivalent of reshape2's melt in collapse?

Tags: r, melt, r-collapse

I melt data frames using the (now deprecated) R package `reshape2` for plotting using `ggplot2`, but just heard of `collapse`, a high performance package for data transformation. Unfortunately, I could not determine the equivalent of `melt` by looking through the cheat sheet provided at https://github.com/SebKrantz/collapse. I would be very appreciative if someone could share the the syntax for melting a data frame using `collapse`.

Comment: My guess would be: https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/reference/pivot.html

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I now see it mentioned in passing in the last line of Fast Data Manipulation

Comment: Not to discourage `collapse` at all, I would advice to pick the functions available within the package you already use. If you already use `data.table` then look into `melt` / `dcast`, if you already work with `tidyverse`, use `pivot_longer` / `pivot_wider` and of course if you aim for using `collapse` as a main data manipulation package, yes then use `pivot` as suggested in other replies.

Comment: All good points, and thank you for your guidance. I'm working with friends, and we have a mixture of dataframes, data tables and xts objects (but no tibbles) in our code, so it must work with all these objects.  I was drawn initially to the tidyverse, but have found that its syntax changes over time, requiring revisions to our code more often than we would like. I'm hoping that collapse proves more stable (and faster) than the tidyverse.

Comment: @ThomasPhilips I can assure you that `collapse` is definitely more stable and robust than the tidyverse. This is a core development objective, the last 3 major updates had no noteworthy API breaking changes and no further API breaking changes are currently planned.

Comment: Good to know! I'm in the process of writing a textbook on Portfolio Management and Risk Analysis with Doug Martin, Stoyan Stoyanov, Bernd Scherer and Kirk Li to be published by Springer in 2024, and have plenty of places in which to use collapse. The book has a focus on reproducibility and a supporting R package (PCRA on CRAN) to allow all the graphs and tables to be reproduced by students. I'll ping my co-authors and tell them about `collapse`.

Answer (score 3):

{collapse}'s reshape command is called `pivot()`, and it does longer, wider and recast pivoting all in one (controlled by the `how` argument, default `how = "longer"`, so by default it very much works like `melt`). Many examples are provided in the [online documentation](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/reference/pivot.html), and the function is also introduced with some discussion in the [Blog Post announcing collapse 2.0](https://sebkrantz.github.io/Rblog/2023/10/17/releasing-collapse-2-0-blazing-fast-joins-reshaping-and-enhanced-r/). To just provide the first 3 examples from the documentation here:

```r
library(collapse)
#> collapse 2.0.3, see ?`collapse-package` or ?`collapse-documentation`

pivot(mtcars) |> head()
#>   variable value
#> 1      mpg  21.0
#> 2      mpg  21.0
#> 3      mpg  22.8
#> 4      mpg  21.4
#> 5      mpg  18.7
#> 6      mpg  18.1
pivot(iris, "Species") |> head()
#>   Species     variable value
#> 1  setosa Sepal.Length   5.1
#> 2  setosa Sepal.Length   4.9
#> 3  setosa Sepal.Length   4.7
#> 4  setosa Sepal.Length   4.6
#> 5  setosa Sepal.Length   5.0
#> 6  setosa Sepal.Length   5.4
pivot(iris, values = 1:4) |> head() # Same thing
#>   Species     variable value
#> 1  setosa Sepal.Length   5.1
#> 2  setosa Sepal.Length   4.9
#> 3  setosa Sepal.Length   4.7
#> 4  setosa Sepal.Length   4.6
#> 5  setosa Sepal.Length   5.0
#> 6  setosa Sepal.Length   5.4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>